# Failure to recognize glMatrixMode() or GL_PROJECTION with all needed libraries given

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, camera

I want to use OpenGL with C++ to create a basic scene with a "camera" (perspective) and an object to look at. I've found a sample code [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/116865-using-openglglut-to-create-3d-scenes/). But for some reason, despite the fact that I've tied all the necessary includes and libs together (see below),

```
// OpenGL init and components:
#include <glload/gl_3_3.h>
#include <glload/gl_load.hpp>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <excpt.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
```

the IDE (Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop) disagrees with me:

[image: identifier undefined for glMatrixMode() and GL_PROJECTION]

If you need more information of a certain kind, please let me know.

=============================================================================

Update: After some fiddling around with opengl-related files, this is what I came up with:

```
// Basics:
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// OpenGL init and components:
#include <glload/gl_3_1_comp.h>
#include <glload/gl_3_2_comp.h>

#include <glload/gl_3_3.h>

#include <glload/gl_4_0_comp.h>
#include <glload/gl_4_1_comp.h>
#include <glload/gl_4_2_comp.h>
#include <glload/gl_4_3_comp.h>
#include <glload/gl_4_4_comp.h>

#include <glload/gl_load.hpp>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <excpt.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
```

And it tells me that GLEW_OK is undefined, albeit it's right there in glew.h:

```
#define GLEW_OK 0
```

Comment: You shouldn't really mix glload's headers with the old GL/gl.h headers. It is quite unclear what you are trying to target, but modern core GL does not have functions like `glMatrix()`. If you want that stuff, you should probably include the <glload/gl..._comp.h> headers. And you shouldn't care too much what intellisense tells you; it is easily confused. Does the code compile?

Comment: @derhass : Great. Now I'm coming up with a bunch of linker errors, first one being `Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __funcptr_glClear C:\Users\Andrey\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\gameLab02\gameLab02\main.obj gameLab02
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're using glew, have you called `glewInit()`?

Also make sure you're checking if the initialization was a success.

```
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err)
{
  /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
}
```

OR, It could be something like [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74454/why-is-glvertexattribdivisor-crashing/74456?noredirect=1#comment135037_74456)
it happened to me this morning, a restart solved my problems

Comment: Now that you point this out: trying to use both glload and GLEW also seems like a bad idea.

Comment: agree with you, i have never used glload myself, but judging from their introduction [here](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/group__module__glload.html) it could be using glew as well, hence the error?

Comment: @derhass : What do you want me to specify? What is the bare minimum I should be using as headers and libraries to eventually render a scene?

Comment: @2am : I tried your chunk of code, and for some reason the IDE sees glewInit as undefined. And judging by what the person from your link had to say, do I really have to update my drived? I just got this laptop two months ago, and I don't want to deal with the manufacturer to get an update.

Comment: @Andrey: It would be nice to know what GL version you are targeting, and what gl (extension) loader you want to use: glload or GLEW?

Comment: @derhass : I really don't know what GL version I'm using. It's really hard to find reliable OpenGL-related files like glut and glew. I found freeglut in one place, glew in another, glload in third, etc. Between glload and GLEW, what would you recommend?

Comment: @Andrey: It is hard to tell what will work best for you. But mixing that stuff will not work. You should have a look at this [explanation for the variuos gl loaders](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51979/discussion-between-andrey-and-derhass)